# How do I access the ID of an LI using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I get the ID of a list element? Whenever I use `this.id` it gives me the ID of the parent table. Here's my code:

```
$('*').bind('tap', function() {
    selectBrick(this.id);
    alert(this.id)
});
```

Comment: maybe your brick is 'transparent' to taps. Try `function(event)` and then `event.target.id`.

Comment: How would I implement that? I don't understand.

Comment: $('*').bind('tap', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
});

Comment: You should reconsider the bind to *. Why do you need that? This will also bind to non visible and structural elements.

Comment: Well, I just wanted to be able to get the ID of *any* element that is clicked.

Comment: @Elliot Bonneville, since events bubble up you could actually probably just bind the `body` element and still get the element which fired the event from event.target.

Comment: I suppose that's true, but I've got it working now and I don't think I want to change it. Thanks for the advice, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your selector `'*'` is binding the tap event to the table. You could try to use the event object and see if what `target` is - this should be the DOM element that was actually subjected to the event.

```
$('*').bind('tap', function(event) {
    selectBrick(event.target.id);
    alert(event.target.id)
});
```